# Encoding clicks and keyboard presses in mutual format to feed the to a Neural Net

Tags: python, neural-network

Inspired by [sentdex's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeETZEOy4VdocT7TOjfSA8a) I wanted to try another game. In the tutorial, Harrison takes key presses and one-hot encodes them ([code here](https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5/blob/master/1.%20collect_data.py)), then trains a [Neural Net](https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5/blob/master/2.%20train_model.py) with X being the image/pixel data and Y being the desired key press. Capturing clicks and their locations is easy, but how can I convert the data to something that I can feed to the NN?

Sample click data format, tuple:

(100, 300, "left_click", True)

(x,  y,  mouse button,  press click=True / unpress click=False)

Comment: by any chance have you solved this as I am currently doing something similar and a bit confused on doing so. thanks

Comment: @hurkaperpa Are you still looking for a solution? I haven't worked on this for a while so I don't remember what was the problem when I posted. Here are two sample data points:

If it a key: (Key, ascii code, button, time):
Key, 52, 4, 1519213046.8934715

If it is a mouse press (button, X, Y, time)
left_down, 501, 357, 1519213047.0355203

You could create a new vector that concatenates both of them, either using a word to id mapping (left_press=1, right_press=2, etc) or one-hot encode all of ascii plus mouse buttons.

Comment: The final result, in case of id mappings could look like:

No keyboard press (three zeros), left button(1), X, Y, time (if needed):
[0, 0, 1, 102, 58, 16182.16]

Keyboard press (1 since it is a key, ascii key, 3 zeros for mouse, and time:
[1, 52, 0, 0, 0, 16182.16]

I don't know about one-hot encoding, but I would prefer this flattened version.